# C# Basic ATM, control flow of menu display

Tags: c#, loops, boolean, repeat

Trying to make a basic ATM program for my C# class.

In short, the program has 4 accounts which have integer values stored already. The program must display first what action the user would like to take (Display balance, Withdraw, Transfer), then take the user to selected menu and be allowed to perform whatever tasks they wish within the program.

Just having problems with my `Display Balance menu`. Want to ask if the user would like to display another balance, and restart the Display Balance menu section(The code section here). Here is what I have:

```
if (ACCselect == 1)
{
    string yesno1 = " ";
    int dispSEL = 1;

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("$$$===Display Balance===$$$");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("\t 1) Savings Account");
    Console.WriteLine("\t 2) Debit Card Account");
    Console.WriteLine("\t 3) Credit Card Account");
    Console.WriteLine("\t 4) Investment Account");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Select account with 1-4: ");

    dispSEL = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    DisplayBalance(dispSEL);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Would you like to select another account? (y/n): ");
    yesno1 = Console.ReadLine();
    if (yesno1.ToUpper() == "Y")
    {
        yesno1a = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Main();
    }
} while (yesno1a == true)
```

This is part of `Main()`. ACCselect refers to the selection the user makes, whether they want Display Balance, Withdraw, etc.

The `DisplayBalance()` method selects the appropriate integer value from an array and displays the corresponding balance.

How can I get my program to repeat this section of code if the user selects "y"? 
If the user selects "n" it loops back to the top of the Main() method alright.

Any help would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this because I did a similar thing in my first year, and I made similar mistakes.

First, you are calling `Main` in order to "jump" to the beginning of `Main`. That works, but it gives you nested calls to `Main`. `Main` has become recursive. Once you exit the inner `Main` invocation, you will jump to the outer `Main` which is still running. Try answering "n" and then try to exit the program. You will have to exit twice.

If you want to repeat an action until a condition is true, you can use this pattern:

```
while(true) { //loop forever
 if (SomeCondition()) break; //exit
 else {
  DoStuff();
 }
}
```

Applied to your problem, it goes like this:

```
while(true) { //loop forever
 dispSEL = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 DisplayBalance(dispSEL);

 Console.Write("Would you like to select another account? (y/n): ");
 yesno1 = Console.ReadLine();

 if (yesno1 == "n") break; //exit
 else continue; //next loop iteration
}
```

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask follow-up questions in the comments.